# Android Studio Kotlin Firebase Authentication issues with email formatting

Tags: firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication

First of all I'm very new to coding, so perhaps this will be easy to explain, but I've been stuck on it for several weeks and I can't seem to find the solution.
I'm doing a tutorial on Firebase authentication, and I'm trying to create a user with email and password. I keep getting this Log: "com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException: The email address is badly formatted."  I'm using a pixel5 emulator, latest version of Android Studio and compileSdk 33.

I will show you my code below:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)


    



    auth = Firebase.auth

    val email = binding.enterEmailtxt.toString().trim()
    val password = binding.enterPasstxt.toString().trim()



   
    binding.CreateAcctBtn.setOnClickListener {

        Log.d("EMAIL STRING:", email)


        auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this) {
                task -\>
                if (task.isSuccessful) {
                    var user: FirebaseUser? = auth.currentUser
                    if (user != null) {
                        Log.d("USER:", user.email.toString())
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.d("USER FAIL:", task.exception.toString())
                }


            }
    }




//I have this user in firebase already
    auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword("email@gmail.com", "password123")
        .addOnCompleteListener(this) {
            task -\>
              if (task.isSuccessful) {
                  //Sign is was successful
                  Log.d("SUCCESS:", "User signed in")
                  Toast.makeText(this, "Signed in Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
              }else {
                  //Not successful
                  Log.d("FAILURE:", "User not signed in")
                  Toast.makeText(this, "Sign in not successful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
              }
        }




}

public override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()
    // Check if user is signed in (non-null) and update UI accordingly.
    val currentUser = auth.currentUser
    if (currentUser != null) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "User is logged in", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        Log.d("LOGIN SUCCESS:", "User is logged in")
    }else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "User is logged out", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        Log.d("LOGIN FAILURE:", "User is logged out")
    }
```

the "EMAIL STRING:" log is so I could see what email string Firebase is actually getting, and in logcat this is what I am seeing:

EMAIL STRING:           com.example.introtokotlinfirebase    D  androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText{8c1ff5b VFED..CL. ......I. 0,0-0,0 #7f0800ba app:id/enterEmailtxt}

Maybe that's normal??  Like I said I'm very new at this.  I do have the input type as textEmailAddress in the XML.

I tried creating a user with several different email addresses that I know are legit, 1 is a gmail address.

I did have a lot of extra code commented out that I deleted just FYI

Thank you! in advance :)

Comment: Alex, thanks for the response.  Is that the link you intended to send?  It's about mapping an array of objects from the database, not authentication.  Unless I'm missing something.

Comment: Oh, sorry about that. I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-authenticate-to-firebase-using-email-and-password-in-jetpack-compose-bd70ca56ea91) will help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirebaseSignInWithEmailAndPassword).